# SharePoint 2010 and ASP.net Cache

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint-2010

We have a web farm of 4 SharePoint 2010 server. As web1, web2, web3, web4 and its AAM is http://xxx.sharepoint.com. Now I am making a web part where some data is going to be cached by `HttpContext.Current.Cache`. Now as we know that ASP.NET cache is limited to server memory and it is not shared between other servers in the web farm, So I created a solution where I will go to each server and in web.config I will fill the server list in the farm with semicolon separated and whenever any thing add to the cache I will send data to the other server and sync the cache and do the same for cache items removed.

Now my problem is how I will call other server individually by its own name in the SharePoint farm.

```
    For example (http://web1/)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used memcache, which is working good :) as expected

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer but you can use [timer jobs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff464297%28v=office.14%29.aspx) on Sharepoint for implementing something on all servers. Note that Sharepoint timer service must be running on all servers and it does not happen real-time(it doesn't take long either).

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Velocity is perfect use case for your scenario. Velocity will provide you distributed and in-memory cache.

Link:
[Build Better Data-Driven Apps With Distributed Caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd861287.aspx)